# GitHub Pages failed to build your site: File to import not found or unreadable: variables

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to build a simple blog with Github Pages and I have tested my changes locally with `jekyll serve bundler`. The problem is when I push my changes to GitHub, I see the following error:

```
Your SCSS file blog/styles.scss has an error on line 15: File to import not found or unreadable: variables. Load path: /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.4/_sass.
```

I looked at `_sass/_variables.scss` file and I don't see any obvious issues.

Any pointers? Appreciate any help (FYI - I new to ruby and jekyll ecosystem)

Comment: Forgot to mention - the repo is at [here](https://github.com/sgolecha/sgolecha.github.io)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the cause of this issue. The problem was that all my blog files were under the `blog/` directory in the repository and GitHub Pages does not use that as the `source` to publish the blog. It expects the `source` to be at the root of the repository. Once I moved all the files to the root of the repository, everything worked fine.